# Calculate difference between two rows in dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to create a column `mr` which is the difference between two rows in column `y`

```
  tDF <- tDF %>%  mutate(days_between = as.numeric(difftime(lubridate::ymd(`Rare event date`), lubridate::ymd(lag(`Rare event date`)), units = 'days'))) %>% rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(y = days_between^0.2777) %>% mutate(mr = abs(y - lag(y)))
```

However, I'm getting `NA` for all the rows in `mr`:

[image]

The expected result is `0.17` for row 3 (1.64 - 1.47)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I guess it is the `rowwise` that creates the issue.  The `lag` after rowwise returns Na as first element for each row and the difference is thus NA.  Just remove the `rowwise` and it should work

Comment: Now that you found the error, please self-answer such that this gets closed. As now it is marked as unanswered

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I added my answer. It says I can accept my answer in 2 days

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @akrun the solution to this is to remove `rowwise`